# SqlAlchemy (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xB4\\xEB\\xC7\\xD1\\xB9\\xCE...' for column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' at row 484")

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xB4\xEB\xC7\xD1\xB9\xCE...' for column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' at row 484")

This error occurs whenever I try to insert a row (for anytable) But I don't have any table which contains 'VARIABLE_VAULE' column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('VARIABLE_VALUE')
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='sw';  /* nothing comes up */
```

How do I locate the table which causes the warning?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/variables-table.html. You're setting some global or session variable to a value that's encoded in a way that's not supported. But it's impossible to say what, since you haven't provided a [mcve], or a proper traceback instead of just the error message.

Comment: I get similar error it's depends of the caracters in my case shows this the error  "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC2\\x91IA I...' for column 'RZIMPO' at row 5")", the row fails is a 'ñ'

Answer (score 1):

The encoding used for Unicode has traditionally been 'utf8'. However, for MySQL versions 5.5.3 on forward, a new MySQL-specific encoding 'utf8mb4' has been introduced, and as of MySQL 8.0 a warning is emitted by the server if plain utf8 is specified within any server-side directives, replaced with utf8mb3. The rationale for this new encoding is due to the fact that MySQL’s legacy utf-8 encoding only supports codepoints up to three bytes instead of four. Therefore, when communicating with a MySQL database that includes codepoints more than three bytes in size, this new charset is preferred, if supported by both the database as well as the client DBAPI, as in:

```
e = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test?charset=utf8mb4")
All modern DBAPIs should support the utf8mb4 charset.
```

[enter link description here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=utf8mb4#charset-selection)

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you are trying to store an emoji using the wrong charset. Change the charset from `utf8` to `utf8mb4`