# Flask SQLAlchemy pymysql Warning: (1366 Incorrect string value)

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, character-encoding, flask-sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm using `flask_sqlalchemy` in my flask application with a local `MySQL (8.0.19)` database. I've never got this issue before (started to develop this app months ago). Not sure what've changed, what component of the app got updated but I'm getting this error out of nowhere at the moment. I've searched and found that it might be some [character encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50653500/6560773), but following the instructions I still get the warning when I open my app:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170:Warning: 
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF6z\\xE9p-e...' for column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' at row 1")
result = self._query(query)
```

This is my url env variable:

```
MYSQL_URL = mysql+pymysql://user:passoword@localhost:3306/testdb?charset=utf8mb4
```

And this is how I create my db `session`:

```
db_url = os.getenv('MYSQL_URL')
engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=True)

Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

This is the most simple usage of the `session`:

```
def row_count():
    return (
        session.query(Value.ValueID).count()
    )
```

When I inspect this local database with HeidiSQL it says its collation is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. I don't know what those suffix specifics mean and there's a ton of utf8mb4 variant available. This is the default value.

[image]

Anyone has any idea how to resolve this warning? What does it mean exactly? As I'm using an ORM I'm not creating any database or running any query by hand, so how should I handle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Incorrect string value" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors)

Comment: Please display the hex of the string in the database.  That might give us some more insight into where the problem lies.

Comment: @RickJames How can I get the value of this string first? It seems like a generated error message. Should I catch it in some way?

Comment: Do `SET NAMES utf8mb4` right after connecting.

Answer (score 0):

ai : accent insensitive

ci : case insensitive

Did your try the following URL:

```
MYSQL_URL = mysql+pymysql://user:passoword@localhost:3306/testdb?charset=utf8mb4_ai_ci
```

Comment: It throws this error:
  `File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 283, in __init__
    self.encoding = charset_by_name(self.charset).encoding
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'`

Comment: which version of MySQL ?

Comment: The version is 8.0.19